# parabolic PDE with pseudomonotone operators

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am looking for a reference where well-posedness of problems
$$u_t + A(t)u  = f$$
is addressed via the Galerkin method where $A$ is a pseudomonotone operator. I am aware that Roubicek's book *Nonlinear partial differential equations with applications* has this but the presentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Let me emphasise that I'd ideally like a solution using the Galerkin method. Does anyone know any good sources? Thank you!

PS: if this is not possible, other suggestions are welcome too. But I am keen to use a Sobolev space setting.